# Convert 2D Array of Points to Graph

Tags: image-processing

I have a two dimensional array of points, which constitute a map. The black pixels mark where the walls are.Each of those points is marked as either wall or empty. Is there an algorithm to find the important points, such as corners and where walls end?Take the following two images for example:

This is the graph I have:
[image: Current graph]

And this is the result I want:
[image: Expected result]

Then I could take those significant points to create a graph of the wall, instead of having to keep track of every pixel.

Comment: is short you have a polygon, you just store the vertex positions!

Comment: Just storing vertices won't be enough if he wants to keep rounded/curved features intact

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/straightedge/

Comment: @MahlerFive rounded figures and circles may be (and should be) approximated to polygons.

Comment: The curvature isn't important. The main issue is I have a lot of pixels that mark sensor data from a robot, but I'd like to turn these messy lines into a simpler polygon representation.

Comment: Try to google "Harris corner detector"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a corner detection filter. Here's a good reference, with some sample code in Java: http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/msn/book/new_demo/corners/